# How to prevent change of case of user-defined components in ReactJS while using react-html-parser?

Tags: reactjs, lowercase, case-conversion

I am trying to convert below string `rawJSX` to JSX using [react-html-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-html-parser).

```
import ReactHtmlParser from "react-html-parser";

function StrToJSX() {
    let rawJSX = `<h1> Hello World! </h1>
    <MyParagraph> I am a programmer. </MyParagraph>`;

    return ReactHtmlParser(rawJSX);
}
```

`react-html-parser` converts all the tags and components to lowercase i.e. it is converting `MyParagraph` component to lowercase as `myparagraph`.

But I don't want change in case in **the components defined by me** i.e. I want that after conversion from a string to JSX, `MyParagraph` should be `MyParagraph`, it shouldn't convert to `myparagraph`.

**Why I don't want change of case:** According to [official documentation of ReactJS](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#user-defined-components-must-be-capitalized), user-defined components must be capitalized. If they are not capitalized, they will be treated as HTML tags.

Comment: Facing same issue, were you able to resolve ths?

Comment: I was not able to resolve the issue. But then I found [html-react-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-react-parser), and it resolved the issue.